# Was bedeutet »scheißhübsch«?

Tags: meaning, colloquial

Was bedeutet es, wenn jemand sagt:

> Du bist scheißhübsch?

Hat das eine positive oder negative Bedeutung?

Ich glaube, *scheiß* bedeutet hier *sehr.* Habe ich recht?

Comment: Same in English: damn cute

Comment: More like: _fucking beautiful_. Pardon my French.

Comment: Scheiß-: Ein häufig verwendeter (aber trotzdem bedeutungsloser) Verstärkerungsvorsilbe.

Answer (score 2):

Nennen wir das mal Jugendsprache - ich glaube auch, dass das "sehr" heissen soll.

> scheißteuer
>
> scheißvornehm
>
> scheißbequem
>
> scheißgefährlich

habe ich schon gehört. *scheißhübsch* (möglicherweise zum Glück) noch nicht. Ob der Begriff unbedingt als Kompliment geeignet ist, weiss ich nicht genau, würde es aber erst mal annehmen.

Der Duden meint dazu

> **sche̱i̱ß-**
>   umgangssprachlich
>
> 1. als Erstglied zusammengesetzter Adjektive, mit Betonung auf beiden Teilen; drückt intensivierend aus.
> 2. dass die mit dem Zweitglied bezeichnete Eigenschaft, die auf jemand/etwas zutrifft, besonders stark ausgeprägt ist.
>      Synonyme:   ganz, sehr

Die Verwendung ist ausgesprochen umgangssprachlich, besonders in der Jugendsprache und nicht für die gehobene - nicht mal für die "normale" - Gesellschaft geeignet.

Answer (score 0):

Also der Sinn ist ja schon geklärt. 
So verwenden würde das aber ein nativ Speaker nicht, denke ich.

Besser passen würde denke ich "verdammt hübsch", da "scheiß" einfach wirklich negativ klingt/ist. 
(Im Gegensatz zu dem "verdammt", was hier meiner Meinung nach keinerlei negativen Beigeschmack hat.)

Comment: Da muss ich widersprechen, umgangssprachlich wird dies sehr wohl verwendet, nicht nur von Jugendlichen

Answer (score 0):

By cursing at you

> "Du bist scheißhübsch!"

would i communicate my intrapsychic conflict of being attracted to you who are so pretty that you distract my self-control and make me lose my cool and self-consciously question my competing self-worth like doubt whether my own attractiveness is up to par with yours to have a chance to equally attract you.

Pragmatically in a nutshell: an attempt at seducing you with my cultured realism and pessimistic wits and at insuring my depressed self-respect beyond your anticipated rejection, packaged in an ambivalent compliment.

A usage of "scheißhübsch" stemming from an appreciation of the ugly or an insight that prettiness in general is detrimental or for its superficiality contrary to beauty seems less likely.